# Show a box on div on hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div in my code in which I have inserted an image. I want that when I hover on that image, a box with some text should be displayed on  the image.....

```
<div id=".image">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSZPFUnMbNKcDHYgjgLqslZtOicCfxph__Jwk95NZGXM_HZ1wzvbGhlrSNi">
    <div id="des">hi</div>
</div>
```

I want to make a box with some text appear on top of the image when it is hovered over.

How can I do that?

I tried following but didnt work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".image").mouseover(function() {
            alert("hello");
            $(this).children(".des").show();
        }).mouseout(function() {
            $(this).children(".des").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Theres like a bizzillliion answers to this.

Comment: search , search , search !!!

Answer (score 1):

Make two divs, one for your image and one for the box with text.

For example div1 (the Image) and div2 (the box with text).

```
.div1 {
background:url('image.jpg');
}

.div2 {
width:20px;
height:20px;
background-color:#000;
}
```

With me so far?

So in HTML you will have...

```
<HTML>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<div class="div1">

</div>

<div class="div2">

TEXT HERE

</div>

</body>

</HTML>
```

Then to display div2 when hovering over div1 you will need to make div2 not display as default, and make the hover commands.

```
.div1 {
    background:url('image.jpg');
    }

.div2 {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#000;
    display:none;
    }
.div1:hover + .div2 {
    display:block;
 }
```

I think this should work :)

Comment: You might have to do <div class="div1"> </div> <div class="div2"> TEXT HERE </div>

Answer (score 0):

First, you declare a div such that it will trail your mouse pointer. Then you can show the div when it is over the image. When mouse leaves the image, the div is hidden. Please check the example fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/B5h6v/

You can implement it using jQuery `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` events